# How to deal with std::out_of_range error in the given code?

Tags: c++, g++, c++14

Below the C++ code is supposed to reverse the vector.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

vector<int> reverseArray(vector<int> a){
    vector<int> b;
    for (int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
        b.at(i) = a.at(a.size()-i-1);
    }
    return b;
}

int main(){
    int input;
    vector<int> arr;

    // read vector
    while(cin >> input){
        arr.push_back(input);
    }

    // print vector
    for (int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
        cout << arr.at(i) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl <<"Reversed vector is:- ";
    vector<int> r_arr = reverseArray(arr);

    // print reversed vector
    for (int i=0;i<r_arr.size();i++){
        cout << arr.at(i) << " ";
    }
}
```

However, an error is being thrown as follows:-

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I checked that a.size()-i-1 is varying from 5 to 0 for a.size() = 6. Why is the code not working then? Where is the problem?

Please help, I'm learning C++ STL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that `b` is the same size as `a` before you start arbitrarily assigning to it. Just an extra constructor parameter should do it:

```
vector<int> reverseArray(vector<int> a){
    vector<int> b(a.size());
    for (int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
        b.at(i) = a.at(a.size()-i-1);
    }
    return b;
}
```

Also, your final loop for printing out the reversed array, is indexing the wrong array in the `cout`. It should read:

```
// print reversed vector
for (int i=0;i<r_arr.size();i++){
    cout << r_arr.at(i) << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`std::vector<int> b` uses the [default constructor (1)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) of `std::vector` which initializes the vector with a size of `0` so `b.at(i)` will always be out of range.

You need to initialize it with the same size as `a` using `std::vector<int> b(a.size())`.

But reversing a container is much easier using the reverse iterators ([`rbegin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rbegin), [`rend()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rend)):

```
std::vector<int> reverseArray(vector<int> a){
    std::vector<int> b(a.rbegin(), a.rend());
    return b;
}
```

so you actually don't need a function for that:

```
cout << endl << "Reversed vector is:- ";
std::vector<int> r_arr(arr.rbegin(), arr.rend());
```

And if it is only about printing/iterating it in revers order, then you don't even need an intermediate vector:

```
// print vector reversed
for (auto it=arr.rbegin(); it!=arr.rend(); it++){
  cout << (*it) << " ";
}
```

And if you want to reverse an existing container in place and you don't need the original order you can use [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)

```
std::reverse(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
for( auto i: arr ) {
  cout << i << " ";
}
```

Except for learning purposes, there is absolutely no reason to manually reverse an array with a loop.

Comment: @user9194161 what do you mean with that? In your code?  in my code?

Comment: Sorry! It was in my code. It is working correctly. Thank you sir.